# WAP to input start no. and end no. Print the series according to the No.s entered ? Using PHP

Tags: php, cakephp

WAP to input start no. and end no. Print the series according to the No.s entered ?

> Note: loop must be used once in a whole php program...

**Eg :**

Start no. **11** , end no. **16**

```
print 11 12 13 14 15 16
```

start no. **21** , end no. **12**

```
print 21 20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12
```

Comment: Compare Both number and write loop according to that, It is very basic.

Comment: What does WAP stand for?

Answer (score 0):

```
if($startNum > $endNo){
   for($i=$startNum;$i>$endNo;$i--){
       echo $i;
       echo '<br/>';
   }
}

if($startNum < $endNo){
   for($i=$startNum;$i<$endNo;$i++){
       echo $i;
       echo '<br/>';
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `range()` php method:

```
$values = range(20, 12);
foreach ($values as $value) {
    echo $value.'<br/>';
}
```

So that it works on both ways (max to min, min to max)